# Can we use secp256r1 to generate valid Ethereum address instead of secp256k1?

Tags: ethereumj

We interact with HSM via [Graphene](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/graphene) to generate EC public/private key for Ethereum blockchain, many tutorials say **secp256k1** to generate valid Eth address, however the Graphene supports only **secp256r1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Ethereum only supports secp256k1 for regular accounts.

Comment: However, `ethereumjs-util` provides function `privateToAddress`, so I would guess that `ethereumj` possibly provides a similar function...? Or have I misinterpreted the question?

Comment: @goodvibration The main functionality from an HSM is to store the private key safely. You do not access the key directly, only through high level operations like signing and verifying messages. If you manipulate the key in your app you do not need an HSM.

Comment: I did not say anything about manipulating the private key, I was referring to the `generate valid Eth address` part of the question.

Comment: @goodvibration Well you need the private key to generate the address.

Comment: To my understanding, the question kind of implies that this user is already taking care of that (`We interact with HSM via Graphene to generate EC public/private key for Ethereum blockchain`), while only asking how to generate the corresponding address.

Comment: @goodvibration From the linked readme graphene is a cryptographic layer above HSM it doesn't know anything about Ethereum. The problem is that graphene only provides elliptic curves primitives for secp256r1.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the issue has been solved by the Graphene team, where they added the secp256k1.